# Swift task continuation misuse; function tried to resume its continuation more than once

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, combine, game-center

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my setup:

```
import SwiftUI
import GameKit
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello")
            .task {
                await authenticateUser()
            }
    }

    func authenticateUser() async -> Bool {
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { vc, error in
                if let error {
                    continuation.resume(returning: false)
                } else {
                    GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated
                    continuation.resume(returning: GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using an async method here because I want to wait for `authenticateUser` to finish before moving on to other code, and this works great, but if I soft close the app and re-open it, I am hit with the error

```
_Concurrency/CheckedContinuation.swift:164: Fatal error: SWIFT TASK
CONTINUATION MISUSE: authenticateUser() tried to resume its
continuation more than once, returning false!
```

So somehow, it seems like the continuation is trying to resume each time the view is reloaded. I'm not sure why this is/how to prevent it, so any help here would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `GKLocalPlayer` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayer) says regarding this `authenticateHandler`:

> … implement this method to handle the multiple times GameKit invokes it during the sign-in process

Because the authentication handler can be called multiple times, we would reach for an `AsyncSequence`, or, more specifically in this case, an `AsyncStream`:

```swift
func authentications() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Bool, Error> {
    AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
        GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { _, error in
            if let error {
                continuation.finish(throwing: error)
            } else {
                GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated
                continuation.yield(GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over that `AsyncSequence`:

```swift
.task {
    do {
        for try await isAuthenticated in authentications() {
            print(isAuthenticated)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

We cannot be more specific than that without knowing how you plan on using this authentication data. But the general idea is that if you are going to possibly yield more than one value, wrap it in a sequence.

Comment: Ah amazing thank you so much/this is exactly what I was looking for! In this case I just wanted to wait for the user to be authenticated so then I could make a call to `GKAchievement.loadAchievements` and know the data would be accurate. So I've made the call to `loadAchievements` inside of this for loop.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for [Authenticating a Player](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/authenticating_a_player) (emphasis added):

> GameKit calls the authentication handler, **possibly several times**, for
> the following cases:
>
> - **If the local player needs to perform some action, GameKit passes a view controller that you must present to the player to complete the
>   authentication.**
> - If the player successfully signs in, GameKit sets the local player’s isAuthenticated property to true and calls the handler again, this
>   time passing nil for both the view controller and error parameters.
>   You can then start the game.
> - If the player decides not to sign in or create a Game Center account, GameKit sets the local player’s isAuthenticated property to
>   false and calls the handler again by passing an error that indicates
>   the reason the player isn’t authenticated. In this case, disable Game
>   Center in your game.
> - If the local player previously signed in on the device when you set the authentication handler, GameKit sets the local player’s
>   isAuthenticated property to true and passes nil for both the view
>   controller and error parameters, and you can start the game.

Your code must be tolerant of being called repeatedly. You are also responsible for presenting the view controller if one is passed.

Generally in SwiftUI, you wouldn't do this with a continuation at all. You'd use a `@State` variable that tracks the current state of the authentication, and set it in the handler. There's no need for an `async` method here.

Comment: "Your code must be tolerant of being called repeatedly" how could this be done in this case?

Comment: It's not clear how your current code works (your example doesn't use the async-ness at all). Generally in SwiftUI, you'd handle this by setting a `@State` variable whenever the authentication state changes, not using an `async` method or continuation.